# Google Play in app purchases V3 "Canceled Products"

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

I am having problems with canceled products. The problem is that they still show up in the app as purchased instead of canceled.

Product is type "Managed." I have canceled this product about 12 hours ago, and cleared my apps data, but Google Play still claims it to be purchased instead of canceled.

This is what I am doing in verifyDeveloperPayload() since mGotInventoryListener points to that to return a boolean to determine if the product is purchased.

```
boolean verifyDeveloperPayload(Purchase p) {
    String payload = p.getDeveloperPayload();

    int purchaseState = p.getPurchaseState();

    Log.d(TAG, "purchaseState = " + purchaseState);

    if(purchaseState == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

From what I read getPurchaseState() should return a number that tells the app if an item is purchased or canceled or refunded.

Is there something I am doing wrong? Or do I just have to wait a little longer for the item to be canceled?

In the developer console it is already "Canceled" and set to "Will not deliver" and I have already received my email from Google Play saying my order has been canceled.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?